# BASH: excluding a directory in "find" command

Tags: bash, find

I'd like to use find command with excluding a directory.

I have this:

```
GLUE="$GLUE -not -iwholename */dir3/*"
```

And I want to use a `GLUE` variable in a `find` command (`find $GLUE [...]`). Unfortunately, instead of `-not -iwholename */dir3/*` in `GLUE` I get `-not -iwholename dir3/file1 dir3/file2 dir3/file3`, i.e., `*/dir3/*` turns into names of files which meet this condition. And, of course, `find` doesn't work because of it. How to stop that?

Comment: Put single quotes around the asterisks: `'*/dir3/*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find ./ -iname ! -iname <dirname of file name to be not part of search results>

find ./ -iname <file name> ! -path "./dirt o be Excluded/*"
```

I hope one will help

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer this question first:

> How can I use `find` to search recursively *while excluding a directory from the search*? My `find` command supports the `-prune` action and the common extensions (e.g., provided by GNU `find`).

You're very lucky that your `find` supports the `-prune` action. Congratulations!

In this case, only add:

```
\! \( -name 'dir_to_exclude' -prune \)
```

This will be false if the current name processed by `find` is `dir_to_exclude`, and at the same time prune (i.e., cut that branch) from the search tree<sup>1</sup>.

Let's try it (in a scratch directory):

```
$ mkdir {a,b,c,d}/{,1,2,3}
$ touch {a,b,c,d}/{,1,2,3}/{file1,file2}
$ tree
.
|-- a
|   |-- 1
|   |   |-- file1
|   |   `-- file2
|   |-- 2
|   |   |-- file1
|   |   `-- file2
|   |-- file1
|   `-- file2
|-- b
|   |-- 1
|   |   |-- file1
|   |   `-- file2
|   |-- 2
|   |   |-- file1
|   |   `-- file2
|   |-- file1
|   `-- file2
`-- c
    |-- 1
    |   |-- file1
    |   `-- file2
    |-- 2
    |   |-- file1
    |   `-- file2
    |-- file1
    `-- file2

9 directories, 18 files
$ find \! \( -name a -prune \)
.
./b
./b/file2
./b/1
./b/1/file2
./b/1/file1
./b/file1
./b/2
./b/2/file2
./b/2/file1
./c
./c/file2
./c/1
./c/1/file2
./c/1/file1
./c/file1
./c/2
./c/2/file2
./c/2/file1
```

Looks good!

---

Now, you shouldn't put your arguments to `find` (or, more generally your commands and arguments) in a variable, but *in an array*! If you don't you'll very soon run into problems with arguments containing spaces or, like in your OP, wildcards.

Put your `glue` stuff in an array: for example, to find all the files that have a `1` in their name and are empty<sup>2</sup>:

```
glue=( '-name' '*1*' '-type' 'f' '-empty' )
```

Then an array of the *exclude this directory*:

```
exclude_dir=( '!' '(' '-name' 'a' '-prune' ')' )
```

Then find all files that have a `1` in their name and are empty, while excluding directory `a` (in the same scratch directory as before):

```
$ find "${exclude_dir[@]}" "${glue[@]}"
./b/1/file1
./b/file1
./b/2/file1
./c/1/file1
./c/file1
./c/2/file1
```

Looks *really* good! (and observe the quotes!).

---

<sup>1</sup>
If you really want to be sure that you're only excluding the directory with name `dir_to_exclude`, in case you have a file called `dir_to_exclude`, you can specify it thus:

```
\! \( -name 'dir_to_exclude' -type d -prune \)
```

<sup>2</sup>
I'm using a lot of quotes here. Just a good habit that actually saves me for the wildcard part `*1*` and for the parentheses too!